# What is the topological data for $(\mathbb Z_n)_p$ theories?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, gauge-theory, research-level, topological-field-theory

Consider the 3d TQFT described by the Lagrangian (Dijkgraaf-Witten with gauge group $\mathbb Z_n$ at level $p$):
$$
\mathcal L=\frac{n}{2\pi} B\wedge\mathrm dA+\frac{p}{4\pi}A\wedge\mathrm dA
$$
with $A,B$ abelian gauge fields. According to ref.1 §5, $n$ can be an arbitrary integer and $p\in\mathbb Z_n$ (or $\mathbb Z_{2n}$, it is unclear: both options are mentioned in the same paragraph). The theory depends on the spin structure of the underlying manifold if and only if $p$ is odd.

**What is the topological data for this theory?** Apparently, there are $n^2$ Wilson lines, labelled by pairs $(n_A,n_B)\in\mathbb Z_n\times\mathbb Z_n$ (see the appendix A on ref.2, although there is probably a typo: these authors write $n_i=0,1,\dots,n$, which corresponds to $\mathbb Z_{n+1}$ instead of $\mathbb Z_n$) such that
$$
\exp\left(in_A\oint A+in_B\oint B\right)
$$

I have three questions:

- Are there really $n^2$ lines? I would expect that the number of lines should depend on $p$ and, in particular, on whether it is even or odd (typically, the number of lines is doubled when the theory depends on the spin structure).
- What is the **topological spin** of a given line $(n_A,n_B)$?
- What are the **fusion rules** of this theory? Being abelian, there is a single line in $(n_A,n_B)\times (n'_A,n'_B)$. It seems natural to expect that this line is in fact $(n_A+n'_A,n_B+n'_B)\ \mathrm{mod}\ n$, but I cannot find any reference for this.

**References.**

1. A. Kapustin, N. Seiberg - *Coupling a QFT to a TQFT and Duality*, https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.0740.
2. T. Banks, N. Seiberg - *Symmetries and Strings in Field Theory and Gravity*, https://arxiv.org/abs/1011.5120.